# Merge two pandas dataframes on multiple columns of different types

Tags: python, r, pandas, merge, matching

I have two pandas dataframes that have a lot of shared key columns, however they may be reported in different data types, for example an ID could be reported as an int in one dataframe and a string in the other and the pandas merge doesn't seem to like that when merging.

I come from R and usually get around this by pasting the columns together to create a matching variable as a string (without actually having to create and store that column) like so:

```
df1$new_col = df2$new_col[match(paste(df1$pk1,df1$pk2,df1$pk3,sep='-'),paste(df2$pk1,df2$pk2,df2$pk3,sep='-'))]
```

Is there any way to do something similar in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just do the conversion of `R` to `pandas` follow your logic here.

```
df1.assign(Newkey=df1.pk1.astype(str)+'-'+df1.pk2.astype(str)+'-'+df1.pk3.astype(str)).merge(df2.assign(Newkey=df2.pk1.astype(str)+'-'+df2.pk2.astype(str)+'-'+df2.pk3.astype(str))[['Newkey','new_col']])
```